# xrandr rotate left right faild

Tags: xrandr

I have an X1 Yoga with a 14'' WQHD and I want to rotate the screen to use it with the stylus but **xrandr** fails to rotate.

```
xrandr --output eDP1 --rotate <orientation>
```

works for **normal** and **inverted**, but returns the following error for **left** and **right** :

```
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
```

Idem for

```
xrandr -o <number>
```

it works properly for **0** and **2** but returns the error :

```
Failed to change the screen configuration!
```

for the values **1** and **3**. 
If re-run *xrandr -o 1* a second time it crash with a blank screen.

**update**
My graphics unit is *Intel® HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2)*.
As driver I installed the package *xserver-xorg-video-intel*

Comment: That means your graphics driver is incomplete and buggy. What exact model of graphics card is it? If it's an Nvidia or ATI chip, which driver are you using (proprietary or free)?

Comment: _HD Graphics 520_ and the package _xserver-xorg-video-intel_ is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the configuration file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` solved the problem.

Answer (score 5):

After I upgrade Xorg to `X.Org X Server 1.19.5`, it solved that issue.
to get the version of Xorg

```
Xorg -version
```

and to upgrade `Xorg` on ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04
```

Comment: This is the right answer for me. I don't have the configuration `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`, so the accepted answer doesn't apply to my case. Installing `xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04
` does the trick for me.

Comment: Same on 16.04 on Intel graphics. Initially second monitor would not display after rotation, installing this solved the issue. More info about HWE here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: Worked for me after a whole day of troubleshooting.

Comment: Worked perfectly after running this and a reboot. Also got this error from the Settings GUI (which I haven't been able to find anywhere, but in case someone else sees this): could not set the configuration for crtc 63

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem but without the file */usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf* .
I find it is caused by the kernel **4.13.0-16**. When I switch to the kernel **4.10.0-38**, xrandr works perfectly.